# Auto Incrementing Array Index (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, addition

just had a search and could not find a question with the appropriate answer. I am trying to add a product_id onto the end of an array, some every time something is added, it's also added to the Array. Currently every time I add the product_id it replaces whatever was there previously. All I get is one product_id at Array[0].Below is the part of my code which add's to the array. I then use

```
print_r($order);
```

to show what is in the array.

```
$order = array();

switch ($action)
    {

    // Add

case "add":

$order[] = $product_id;
        break;
        }
```

Here is the entire code from the page minus some MySQL stuff.

```
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_GET['action']))
    {
    $action = $_GET['action']; //Get's action from the URL
    }

if (isset($_GET['product_id']))
    {
    $product_id = $_GET['product_id']; //the action from the URL
    }

// if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error message



if ($product_id && !productExists($product_id))
    {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
    }

switch ($action)
    { //decide what to do

    // Add

case "add":

$order[] = $product_id;

    if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        $productadd = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_basket (customer_id, product_id, basket_status) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user'] . "','$product_id','basket')");
        mysql_query($productadd);
        break;
        }
      else
        {

        $productadd = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_basket (customer_id, product_id, basket_status, user_type) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['guestuser'] . "','$product_id','basket', 'guest')");
        mysql_query($productadd);
        break;
        }

    // Remove

case "remove":
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        $productremove = sprintf("DELETE FROM tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "' AND product_id = '$product_id'");
        mysql_query($productremove);
        break;
        }
      else
        {
        $productremove = sprintf("DELETE FROM tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['guestuser'] . "' AND product_id = '$product_id'");
        mysql_query($productremove);
        break;
        }

    // Empty

case "empty":
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        $empty = sprintf("DELETE FROM tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "' AND order_status = 'basket'");
        mysql_query($empty);
        break;
        }
      else
        {
        $empty = sprintf("DELETE FROM tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "' AND order_status = 'basket'");
        mysql_query($empty);
        break;
        }
    }

if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_basket a INNER JOIN tbl_products b ON a.product_id = b.product_id WHERE a.customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
    }
  else
    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_basket a INNER JOIN tbl_products b ON a.product_id = b.product_id WHERE a.customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['guestuser'] . "'");
    }
```

Comment: seems like a problem with variable scope. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Please provide more code. If there is a surrounding loop - show it.

Comment: I have updated the question with more code.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the array being reinitialised every time.

Answer (score 0):

You clear the previous values in `$order` when you do `$order = array();`
Just delete that line and `$order[] = $product_id;` will add another item to the array.

Comment: That still replaces everything. So the only code for the array I currently have is $order[] = $product_id;

Comment: @user3521635 check the array before you add to it to see what it has in it.